# How do you use useMutation from react-apollo-hook to execute a delete mutation?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-apollo, react-hooks, react-apollo-hooks

I'm trying to use the `useMutation` hook from `react-apollo-hook`s to execute a delete mutation, but I'm having difficulty passing the ID value of the post to the mutation hook in the following code:

```
const Posts = () => {
    const { data, error, loading } = useQuery(GET_POST)
    const onDeleteHandler = useMutation(DELETE_POST, {
        variables: { id }
    })
    if (loading) return <div>...loading</div>
    if (error) return <div>Error</div>

    return data.posts.map(({id, title, body, location, published, author}) => {
        return  (
            <div className="card" key={id}>
                <p>id: {id}</p>
                <p>title: {title}</p>
                <p>body: {body}</p>
                <p>location: {location}</p>
                <p>published: {published}</p>
                <p>author: {author.name}</p>
                <Link to={`/post/${id}/edit`}>
                    Edit
                </Link>
                <button 
                    onClick={onDeleteHandler}>
                    Delete
                </button>
            </div>
        )
    })    
}
```

I cannot include the `useMutation` inside the `onClick()` property since a hook cannot be used as a callback function. I tried using `const inputRef = useRef()` and passing `inputRef.current.value`, but kept getting undefined.

Comment: read [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html#passing-arguments-to-event-handlers)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the `react-apollo-hooks` [docs](https://github.com/trojanowski/react-apollo-hooks):

> You can provide any mutation options as an argument to the useMutation hook or to the function returned by it

So you can omit the variables when calling `useMutation`:

```
const onDeleteHandler = useMutation(DELETE_POST)
```

and then pass them in when calling the handler:

```
onClick={() => onDeleteHandler({ variables: { id } })}>
```

**Note**: `react-apollo-hooks` is now deprecated since `react-apollo` now supports hooks. The API is a bit different, so usage would look like this:

```
const [onDeleteHandler, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(DELETE_POST)
```

Comment: I tried this implementation but I keep getting the error :
`TypeError: onDeleteHandler is not a function`

I call useMutation and the handler just as you have it above.

Comment: @Avery-DanteHinds please see added note

Comment: Thanks for the update! However I'm still getting errors when I try delete mutations using the react-apollo hooks. 
`Uncaught (in promise) Error: Network error: Response not successful: Received status code 400`
If you get a chance I would appreciate if you checked out my [repo](https://github.com/thelovesmith/GRANDstack-test/blob/3858f01f5fa1b1d347b7d90bc8e7f1669f515d93/ui/src/CreateUser.js#L75). I don't know where I'm at fault in the code. The useQuery hook and createUser useMutation work but I can not figure out how to delete from the UI

Comment: @Avery-DanteHinds 400 means your mutation is malformed or otherwise invalid. Check the actual response from the server to determine the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do the same with `useQuery()`.